# How to run 1 function with multiple dataset?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

Assuming I got 20 set of data which I read it as df1,df2,df3,df4...df20.
(Any other smart way to read or store dataframe?)

my function be like:

```
def CalculateEMA(x,window):    
    sma = x.rolling(window, min_periods=window).mean()[:window]
    rest = x[window:]
    EMA_window=(pd.concat([sma, rest]).ewm(span=window,adjust=False).mean()).sum())

    return EMA_window
```

And I wish to return a EMA for all 20 data frame and store as **X**. 
So my final output will be X = [x1,x2,x3,x,x,x,x,x...x20]. Where **x1** is the **Sum** of EMA fucntion for df1 and **x2** is second dataset df2 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop throughout your dataframes if you stock them in a list :

```
X=list()
list_df = [df1,df2,...,df20]
for df in list_df:
    X.append(CalculateEMA(df,window))
```

Comment: if there any other method to read data instead of reading 1 by 1? Like i have to read it like df 1 = pd.read_csv('....'), repeat 20 times

Answer (score 0):

to read all the csv files in a folder you can make use of os function

```
    import os
    path_to_dir='<your path>'
    filenames = os.listdir(path_to_dir)
    csvs=[f for f in filenames if f.endswith('csv')]
    out=[]
    for path in csvs:
        df=pd.read_csv(path)
        out.append(CalculateEMA(df,window))
```